# What does the following Trace represent:

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-electrodynamics, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

I have a two level system with outcomes 'a' and 'b'. Let $P^a$ and $P^b$ be the corresponding projection operators.

Then
$$Tr[P^a U(t_2 - t_1) \rho (t_1)U^{\dagger} (t_2 - t_1)]$$ is the probability of obtaining outcome 'a' at time $t_2$.

Also, $$Tr[U(t_2 - t_1) P^a\rho (t_1)U^{\dagger} (t_2 - t_1)]$$ is the probability of obtaining outcome 'a' at time $t_1$.

What is the meaning of
$$Tr[P^a U(t_2 - t_1)  P^a  \rho (t_1)U^{\dagger} (t_2 - t_1)]$$

Comment: Did you just make up this expression, or is there a reason you ask?

Comment: Yes. This Trace is useful in studying the quantum correlations.

Comment: Can you explain this connection?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think $$I=Tr[P^a U(t_2 - t_1)  P^a  \rho (t_1)U^{\dagger} (t_2 - t_1)]$$  has any clear physical meaning.

First of all, 
$$Tr[U(t_2 - t_1)  P^a  \rho (t_1)U^{\dagger} (t_2 - t_1)]$$ 
is the probability to measure $a$ at time $t_1$ only because we can get rid of the evolution operators $U$, so they are redundant.

Now, $U(t_2 - t_1)  P^a  \rho (t_1)U^{\dagger} (t_2 - t_1)$ is not a time evolved density matrix, since it does not have the properties of a density matrix (it does not have a trace equal to one, for instance). Thus,  $I$ cannot be interpreted as a projection of a time evolved system.

What would make more sense is $$Tr[P^a U(t_2 - t_1)  P^a  \rho (t_1)P^aU^{\dagger} (t_2 - t_1)]$$ which is the probability to be in $a$ at time $t_2$, knowing that the system was in $a$ at time $t_1$ (and had a probability $Tr[P^a  \rho (t_1)]$ to be in $a$ at $t_1$).

Answer (score 1):

The real part of $Tr[P_aUP_a\rho U^\dagger]$ can be related to correlation functions as follows:

The probability to have the particle in state $a$ at time $t_2$ provided it was in state $a$ at time $t_1$ is $Tr[P_aUP_a\rho P_a U^\dagger]$. The probability to have the particle in state $a$ at time $t_2$ when it was in state $b$ at time $t_1$ is $Tr[P_aUP_b\rho P_b U^\dagger]$.

Then note that 
$$
Tr[P_aU\rho U^\dagger] - Tr[P_aU(P_a\rho P_a + P_b\rho P_b)U^\dagger] = Tr[P_aUP_a\rho P_bU^\dagger] + Tr[P_aUP_b\rho P_aU^\dagger] =\\
Tr[P_aUP_a\rho(I - P_a)U^\dagger] + Tr[P_aU(I - P_a)\rho P_aU^\dagger] = \\
Tr[P_aUP_a\rho U^\dagger] + Tr[P_aU\rho P_aU^\dagger] - 2 Tr[P_aUP_a\rho P_aU^\dagger] 
$$
But 
$$
Tr[P_aU\rho P_aU^\dagger] = \left(Tr[P_aUP_a\rho U^\dagger]\right)^*
$$
so rearrange to get
$$
\mathcal{R} \left(Tr[P_aUP_a\rho U^\dagger]\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left( Tr[P_aU\rho U^\dagger] + Tr[P_aUP_a\rho P_aU^\dagger] - Tr[P_aUP_b\rho P_bU^\dagger]\right)
$$

On the other hand, the imaginary part relates to 
$$
Tr[P_aUP_a\rho P_bU^\dagger] - Tr[P_aUP_b\rho P_aU^\dagger] =\\
Tr[P_aUP_a\rho(I - P_a)U^\dagger] - Tr[P_aU(I - P_a)\rho P_aU^\dagger] = \\
Tr[P_aUP_a\rho U^\dagger] - Tr[P_aU\rho P_aU^\dagger]  =  \mathcal{I} \left(Tr[P_aUP_a\rho U^\dagger]\right)
$$
but its physical meaning, if there is any (see Adam's answer) doesn't seem that obvious.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you suggest some reference containing the related stuff?

Comment: I honestly did this off the top of my mind, playing a bit with possible combinations. I tried to look up something similar but didn't find much, and whatever seemed related was behind a paywall. If you have access, look up "projection techniques for two-level atoms", there are some older articles that may be useful, e.g. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037596017490810X, http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.11.1001, and "projection operator methods" in general, lots of literature on this.